# Test with DataJpaTest given no bean of type ServletContext

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, junit4, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test using DataJpaTest. I get the following error

> Description:
>
> Parameter 6 of constructor in
>   springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper
>   required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' that could not
>   be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' in
>   your configuration.

I have tried defining a EmbeddedServletContainerFactory in the test configuration. 
When i use @SpringBootTest it works, but I don't think it is good to use integration testing for everything.

I even tried to fool it by using a mockbean of Servlet Context, but still it doesn't work. Is there a way around this?

Also, why is this error happening, I'm new to testing so, I do not have full knowledge about it.

The following is my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class GprsDeviceRepositoryTest{
    @Autowired
    GprsDeviceRepository gprsDeviceRepository;

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void test(){
    ..}
}
```

Comment: Could it be, that you are using some `@Enable...` annotations on your main spring boot class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. Consider moving them all to their corresponding configuration classes, for swagger with '@EnableSwagger' e.g.: [@DataJpaTest with SpringFox @EnableSwagger2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678550/11133168)

Comment: The main spring boot class extends `@SpringBootServletInitializer` and excludes certain config files, other than that there is no `@Enable`

Comment: You should check whether the problem originates from swagger. You could try and disable your swagger configuration while testing like: ```@Configuration @EnableSwagger2 @Profile("!test") public class SwaggerConfig { ...... }```

Comment: I've tried that too, it gives a different error `Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping'` and `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [ResourceHttpRequestHandler`, then i tried by putting `@WebAppConfiguration`, but i still get the above error

Comment: @MohendraAmatya were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I added an issue in Spring Boot to improve this error message: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16936

Comment: @FlorianDe removing EnableSwagger2 from main application class solved the issue. Thanks. Can you explain if you understand the reason?

Comment: @FlorianDe this should be an actual answer. Thanks!